# App not installed- the package appears to be corrupt in ionic3?

Tags: android-studio, ionic3

I have an error during generating the release build in ionic3. The problem is that the app build is generated properly but it is not installed. I have to live this app in the play store and I have tried the following commands for generating the android build:

1st I tried this :

> sudo ionic cordova android --prod --release

Sucessfullly generated build but after I open it on mobile: "app not installed error"

Next I tried:

> sudo npm cache clear --force
>
> sudo ionic cordova rm android
>
> sudo ionic cordova add android@6.4.0

I have tried above commands with different android versions, but I have got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ionic cordova build android --prod --release` to build the unsigned apk for release. Or if you're just testing `ionic cordova run android` you can use the `--device` flag if you want to run it on a physical device.

Comment: @kapilsoni are you trying to build the apk for release?

Comment: means sir i don't understand?

Comment: sir i have run this cmd and successfully open but why we need this cmd?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186491/discussion-between-kapil-soni-and-alex87).

Answer (score 0):

Remove project's node module using

```
 rm -rf node_modules
```

then remove platform manually from your root file,then install node module using

```
 npm install
```

then add platform using

```
ionic cordova plaform add android
```

then try to run/build again.

Comment: what is the error after that,share it here so i can help you out.